# Get nth object in class Java

Tags: java, class, object

If I have this code:

```
public class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String hello = "Hello World";
    int num = 7;
        }
    }
```

And if I wanted to print out String hello and int num, I would normally do:

```
System.out.println(hello);
System.out.prinln(num);`
```

However, can I access hello and num in a different way, like:

```
Foo(0); // for String hello
Foo(1); //for int num
```

Comment: What results are you trying to produce?

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242) What bigger goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to accomplish by doing this but yoy could make the variables public, and you don't need a main method. You would then access by doing Foo f = new Foo (); f.hello or f.num.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hello` and `num` are declared within `main()`, noway you could access it with class name, as they won't exist beyond the scope of `main()`.

I guess you are probably asking for arrays instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] foo = {"hello world", 7};
    System.out.println(foo[0]);//hello world
    System.out.println(foo[1]);//7
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I mean